# How to handle Location denial in App that is heavily dependent on current Location?

Tags: ios, location

i am developing an App, where the Location is absolutely necessary.
What is the most user-friendly way to handle the **denial** of the user location permission. My app is practically useless without the users location.
Should i just close it, with an Alert ?

Comment: Simply put up a screen indicating the need for enabling location services and provide a button to launch your app's setting page, along with instructions on what to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think iOS doesn't like us to quit or exit from the app programatically. I've seen apps that got rejected because of this.

In my opinion, it would be best to put a full screen view with some cool images with a message to the user that you are sorry and also would describe the need of location usage